# can not save the whole code of soundcloud embed code to the database

Tags: php, embed, soundcloud, htmlspecialchars

I'm trying to insert the coundcloud embed code to the database to play audio files from soundcloud on a webpage. the embed code is like this

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks
/00112233&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;
show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
```

using this php code

```
$code=htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['code'],ENT_QUOTES);
echo $code;
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into audio (Code) values (:code)");
$stmt->bindParam(':code',$code);
$stmt->execute();
```

But it does not save the whole code the echo line prints this "which is saved to the database"

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"  
src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/00112233
```

and does not get this part of the code

```
&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;
show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
```

so how to change the php code to get the whole embed code?

Comment: php doesn't truncate strings. you probably haven't defined a big enough field in your DB to store all that. e.g. `code` is `varchar(128)` or something, and should be `text` instead.

Comment: this code is printed before inserting into the database not after and the field is 'text'

Comment: then start basic debugging: `var_dump($_REQUEST['code'])`, make sure that the full html is actually arriving properly.

Comment: the whole code is sent via url for testing and via ajax call in actual project. the var_dump printed the first part of the embed code and didn't echo the second ignored part

Comment: are you sure it's "not printing"? it's html. your browser can/will try to render it. did you do a view source to see the raw output?

Comment: it printed the first part as i mentioned and stopped at "&amp;color=......"

Comment: well, like you said. "var_dump printed the fisrt part", whcih means that whatever is sending the code over is whatever's causing the truncation, or something upstream of PHP is doing it (eg webserver-level security system/limit).